# Protobuf: is there a way to define and use flaggable enumerators?

Tags: c#, enums, protocol-buffers

C# has the possibilities for flaggable enumerators. This is very handy to e.g. options:

```
[Flags]
public enum Options 
{
    None    = 0,
    Option1 = 1,
    Option2 = 2,
    Option3 = 4,
    Option4 = 8
}
```

In Protobuf it is possible to assign custom values to the enumerator values but is lacking (as fas as I know) some attribute to mark the enum as flaggable.

Does anybody know a trick to get flaggable enums in Protobuf?

Comment: I think it's more of a GitHub rather than Stackoverflow question

Comment: Do you mean in the .proto schema language? If so: no. Although if you're just using c#, I think protogen (protobuf-net's tool) can add [Flags], but it won't enforce the values

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following:

```
[ProtoMember(20, DataFormat = DataFormat.TwosComplement)]
public Options OptionsEnum {get;set;}
```

Comment: This is a: redundant (enums are done like this by default), and b: probably not what OP is asking; and c: it is protobuf-net specific (question isn't clear about that bit)